# Get Formula Value from WORD table VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I do have a table defined in WORD and I need to take the formula defined in one of the table's cells.

I have setup the formula like following :

```
Selection.InsertFormula Formula:="=MAX(A1:B1)", NumberFormat:=""
```

But when I want to get the Formula from the table , It throws me `"Expected Function or Variable"`

This is how I do want to take the formula from the Word's table cell :

```
Dim formula As Variant
formula = Selection.Cells("A1:C2").Formula
```

But..using this I cannot get the needed formula.

This is the full code I have :

```
ActiveDocument.tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:= _
    3, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
    wdAutoFitFixed

Selection.TypeText Text:="12"
Selection.InsertFormula Formula:="=MAX(A1:B1)", NumberFormat:=""

MsgBox Selection.Cells("C1").Formula, vbOKOnly
```

I create a 2x3 Table , on the first column and the second I have inserted 2 numbers ("A1" = 1 , "B1" = 2 ) and in the third column (C1) I have inserted the respective formula.

When I try to print the Formula from the existing table, it gives me the `"Expected Function or Variable"` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that `Formula` is write-only. I couldn't find that unequivocally in the docs, though the docs did say that `Formula` creates a `Field`.

Maybe this will achieve what you're after:

```
Sub test()
    Dim t As Word.Table
    Set t = ThisDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:= _
        3, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
        wdAutoFitFixed)

    t.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "15"
    t.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "20"
    t.Cell(1, 3).Formula Formula:="=MAX(A1:B1)", NumFormat:=""

    MsgBox t.Cell(1, 3).Range.Fields(1), vbOKOnly
    Set t = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note: the above retrieves the formula. If you want to retrieve the result of the formula, use `Cell(1,3).Range.Text`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Man , you're great! This works perfectly! Thanks you.